# RTCEAGLVideoView orientation change freezes the stream

Tags: ios, cordova, webrtc

I inherited an `iOS` `webRTC` app from someone else and now i am stuck with a problem for a code i am not familiar with.

It's a pretty generic webRTC video stream inside a Cordova iOS app. The problem im trying to solve is, that the video stream freezes, upon device orientation change. So when I change from `lansdscape` to portrait, the stream freezes. The app is landscape only, so therefore I would prefer that the video stream never changes orientation in the first place. Question is, how can I prevent a webRTC `Videostream` to switch orientations.

The app uses the `RTCEAGLVideoView` class to display the video stream. If anyone has any ideas for me where to even start to prevent that view from switching and therefor freezing, you would save my day.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `RTCCameraPreviewView` for your local stream and `RTCMTLVideoView` for your remote stream.

As you read this post it has fixes for the same:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7442

Also update your GoogleWebRTC SDK in case you are using older version.